# Get upstream environment variables - Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can we obtain upstream environment variables in jenkins scripted pipeline?

While going through [documentation](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild) and came across getBuildCauses and upstreamBuilds. And bit googling came across some cases of these functions

```
def causes = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()
def upstream = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause)
def upstream = currentBuild.upstreamBuilds
```

unfortunately, none of the implementation obtain environment variables from the upstream. Can some one demonstrated simple scripted pipe line example that prints upstream environment variables ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about passing them as parameters? That would be more explicit and would show the flow of data more clearly.

Comment: @smelm Unfortunately, we are restricted by our current infrastructure for passing parameters to downstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def upStreamBuilds = currentBuild.upstreamBuilds
if (!upStreamBuilds.isEmpty()) {
  // Only immediate upstream
  Run<?,?> upstream = upStreamBuilds.get(0).getRawBuild()
  def upstreamEnvVars  = upstream.getEnvironment(TaskListener.NULL)
}
```

Comment: can we also set these variables?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc of UpstreamCause](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UpstreamCause.html):

```
getUpstreamRun
@CheckForNull
public Run<?,?> getUpstreamRun()
Since: 1.505
```

This might return the object representing the `Run` that triggered your run (and so was its UpstreamCause).

From the [Javadoc of Run](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html):

```
EnvVars getEnvironment()
Deprecated. 
as of 1.305 use getEnvironment(TaskListener)
-----
EnvVars getEnvironment(TaskListener listener)
Returns the map that contains environmental variables to be used 
for launching processes for this build.
-----
Map<String,String>  getEnvVars()
Deprecated. 
as of 1.292 Use getEnvironment(TaskListener) instead.
```

Hope this might get you started.

Comment: I tried doing some thing that look s as you mentioned,But I am missing some thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389501/getupstreamrun-from-jsonarray-obtained-from-build-causes