# getUpstreamRun from JSONArray obtained from Build causes

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying [getUpstreamRun()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UpstreamCause.html#getUpstreamRun--) in order to get Run object.

```
def causes = currentBuild.getBuildCauses()
// List<Cause.UpstreamCause> upstreamCauses = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause')
def upstreamCauses = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause')

for (Cause cause : upstreamCauses) {
  echo "currentCause: ${cause}"
  if (cause instanceof Cause.UpstreamCause) {
    Cause.UpstreamCause upstreamCause = (Cause.UpstreamCause)cause;
    Run<?, ?> upstreamRun = upstreamCause.getUpstreamRun();
    if (upstreamRun != null) {
      def env = upstreamRun.getEnvironment(TaskListener.NULL)
      println env
    }
  }
}
```

It's failing (if condition is not satisfied) at `if (cause instanceof Cause.UpstreamCause)` unable to reach `getUpstreamRun()` function call. Looks like i am missing some kind of type casting

varible `upstreamCauses` looks like this and is of type "`net.sf.json.JSONArray`"

```
[[_class:hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause, 
 shortDescription:Started by upstream project "mod_production-controller- 
 g5/v1.0_handler_mod_production-controller-g5" build number 7, 
 upstreamBuild:7, 
 upstreamProject:mod_production-controller-g5/v1.0_handler_mod_production-controller-g5, 
  upstreamUrl:job/mod_production-controller-g5/job/v1.0_handler_mod_production-controller-g5/
]]
```

currentCause

```
[_class:hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause, 
 shortDescription:Started by upstream project "mod_production-controller- 
 g5/v1.0_handler_mod_production-controller-g5" build number 7, 
 upstreamBuild:7, 
 upstreamProject:mod_production-controller-g5/v1.0_handler_mod_production-controller-g5, 
  upstreamUrl:job/mod_production-controller-g5/job/v1.0_handler_mod_production-controller-g5/
]
```

Note how to convert this JsonArray to appropriate format to obtain run item. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `currentCause` is an array, you may want to extract its first member:

```
Cause.UpstreamCause upstreamCause = (Cause.UpstreamCause)(cause[0])
```

Comment: unfortunately, no luck. Cause looks as mentioned above.